# USB Hybrid TV Turner Savvy TV 2.0 (TOSHIBA)

Tags: drivers, usb, tv

I have a USB Hybrid TV Turner Savvy TV 2.0 (TOSHIBA)  and I want to install it in my laptop (Hp Elitebook 6930p) I'm using ubuntu 14.10 32 bits.
Please help me to install or to find the drivers and programs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any driver for the Toshiba USB Hybrid TV Turner Savvy TV 2.0 under Linux.

Source: [ivtvdriver.org](http://ivtvdriver.org/index.php/Supported_hardware)